# How to refer to parent class' class variable without an instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class A():
    a = [1, 2]

class B(A):
    a = super().a + [3]
```

Gives the error:

```
 RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

I want the result to be

```
 class B(A):
     a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Use `A.a + [3]`

Comment: Based on your comments to the questions, you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `A.a` instead of super.

but you cannot call super when you didn't create an instance. like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):        
        self.a = [1, 2]

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.a += [3]
```

Then when you create an instance:

```
i = B()

print(i.a)
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I realize my situation is actually different. I want `B` to be a mixin, providing [3] to `.a` for any class. Also, in my situation - I am forced to deal with the class variables and am not able to redefine the `__init__`.

Comment: Let me check your case.

Comment: If `B` is a mixin, I guess that you should add `B` to other classes, not them to `B`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

class variables could be accessed by your **class** and at the-same time **instances of the class.**
So what happens here is that when we try to access an attribute on an instance, it first checks whether the instance contains the attribute; if it doesn't, it checks if the parent class or any class it inherits from contains the attributes.

```
class A(): 
    a = [1, 2] 

class B(A): 
    a = A.a + [3]
```

**test**:

```
print(A.a)  # access class variable using the class
print(B.a)  # access class variable using the class inheritance as B inherit from A
ins = A()   # initializing instance of class A
print(ins.a)  # access class variable using instance of the class
```

**output**:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

as you can see, We get the-same output.

Comment: I want to use it as a mixin though, so no reference to `A`

Comment: i'm not sure what do you mean with mixin, sorry.